# How to solve the [WinError127] when running pytorch in CPU only?

Tags: deep-learning, cpu, nvidia

I am trying to run this machine learning model `https://github.com/TimotheeMickus/codwoe/tree/main/code` for learning purposes and I don't have a GPU on my PC. I have tried all types of shenanigans such as
`os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]=""` and `torch.cuda.is_available = lambda : False` and `device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')` however, nothing works.

I installed `torch==1.8.1` from the official website with cpu-only version and it asks me to install nvidia drivers. When I update pytorch using the official website it also gives me another error:

```
OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found. Error loading "C:\...\Anaconda3\envs\codwoe\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\c10_cuda.dll" or one of its dependencies.
```

Since I don't have a GPU on my PC, I don't see a point in installing a nvidia driver or even cuda. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: Did you try installing using pip instead of conda?

Comment: I tried, still same problem :(